# Display Multiple pipeline Values Of Same Get-Content

Tags: powershell

I am trying to get the string value in csv file.

```
$path = "product.csv" 
Get-Content $path | Select-String -AllMatches -Pattern "[^\x00-\x79]"
```

I successfully grab the string, however I wish display the line numbers then the string values.

```
Example Output:
LineNo    String
1         a
2         b
3         c
```

I did successfully grab the linenumber using below command. How should I combine the command with the first command so the output will be alike the example output?

```
Get-Content $path | Select-String -AllMatches -Pattern "[^\x00-\x79]" |  Select-Object LineNumber
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want the entire line, select the `Line` property:

```
... |Select-Object LineNumber,Line
```

If you only want the part of the line that was matched by the pattern, you'll need a calculated property to grab the `Value` from the `Matches` property:

```
... |Select-Object LineNumber,@{Name='String';Expression={$_.Matches.Value}}
```